# Describing all Sylow 2-subgroups of the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

We are trying to find all Sylow 2-subgroups of an arbitrary dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$.

In the case that $n$ is odd, any Sylow 2-subgroup must have order 2, and it is fairly easy to deduce the set of elements in $D_n$ of order 2.

However, in the case that $n=2m$ is even, we see that $|D_n|=2\cdot 2m$ is divisible by $2^2$ (but not $2^3$), so that every Sylow 2-subgroup has order 4. We are not having luck in finding all subgroups of order 4 in $D_n$, and are wondering if anyone has any hints or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: There are two kinds of groups of order $4$, the cyclic kind, and the ones isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. The cyclic kind requires a generator of order $4$, which can only be found in the rotation subgroup (all the reflections have order $2$). Fortunately, the Klein 4-group is abelian, so you need to have two elements of order $2$ that commute. If these are two reflections, one can show that their product must be the unique rotation of order 2. If it is a rotation and a reflection, the rotation must the order 2 rotation. So either way, such a subgroup contains the center.